# Reshape data after boolean indexes filtering

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, dataframe, numpy-ndarray

I have a data set called `DATA` which regroup several 3D tables from `N=173` files of individual shape `(4, 4, 64)` so at the end the numpy array called `DATA` has shape `(173, 4, 4, 64)`. In each individual file I have a column which is a boolean column to specify if the data is good or bad. In order to filter my data I use then boolean conditions:

```
cond = DATA[:,3,:,:]==False  
DATA_filtered = DATA[:,1,:,:][cond]
```

with the following shapes:

```
np.shape(DATA)
Out[854]: (173, 4, 4, 64)

np.shape(cond)
Out[855]: (173, 4, 64)
```

But since I use this technique at then end I have a 1D array and all the structure of the initial DATA set is lost. One technique is to use the `reshape` function used for `numpy.array` but this technique works only if at then end the dimension remains the same. In the case where the boolean conditions induce tables of variable size, we do no longer can predict and ask for a reshape. So is there a way to filter data but keeping the global shape of the data with size which can vary depending on the flag used in the data?

Here is a minimal example:

```
TEST = np.ones((173,4,4,64))
FLAG = np.random.choice(a=[False, True], size=(173,4,64))

cond = FLAG==False

data = TEST[:,0,:,:][cond]
```

Output :

```
np.shape(data)
Out[868]: (22167,)
```

Expected Output:

```
np.shape(data)
Out[868]: (173,4,)
```

with for example `data[:,1,:]`, a subset with non equals arrays size between 0 and 64 accross the 174 table depending of the data filtering which have been flagged or not.

Thank you in advance

Comment: On an nD tensor, you can eliminate an entire n-1 D slice, but not random portions here and there. E.g., in 2D you can eliminate a whole column or row, but not an isolated element. In 3D, you can eliminate a whole plane (xy, yz, or zx) but not an isolated 1D column. The kind of slicing you want to do would create ragged arrays ("make holes in your 4D tensor"), and are therefore not doable. However, as per the current answer, `numpy` has "masked arrays" precisely for that kind of cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Masked Array is your solution

In many circumstances, datasets can be incomplete or tainted by the presence of invalid data. For example, a sensor may have failed to record a data, or recorded an invalid value. The numpy.ma module provides a convenient way to address this issue, by introducing masked arrays.

A masked array is the combination of a standard numpy.ndarray and a mask

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.ma as ma

x = np.array([1, 2, 3, -1, 5])
mx = ma.masked_array(x, mask=[0, 0, 0, 1, 0])
mx.mean() # without taking the invalid data into account
```

Output

```
2.75
```

All the above taken from [Masked array](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/maskedarray.generic.html#accessing-the-mask)
So you might as well read it form there